# Run the same command in several servers with SSH from MacOSX

Tags: ssh, mac-osx

Is there some program to run the same command in several servers with SSH from MacOSX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using [csshX](http://code.google.com/p/csshx/):

[image]

Comment: I think iTerm2 and Command+Shift+I on multiple panes is a better option now. I have tried both.

Answer (score 10):

iTerm2 can do it. Create one bookmark per server and set the command for each bookmark to ssh . Then use the 'send input to all tabs' feature. You can open a bunch of bookmarks at once using the bookmarks window (cmd-m). https://iterm2.com/index.html

Comment: Just to update everyone, iTerm2 has a new URL :)
http://iterm2.com/

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/peikk0/tmux-cssh is worth trying. Not brew-installable, but it’s just a simple shell script at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peikk0/tmux-cssh/master/tmux-cssh — so do:

```bash
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/peikk0/tmux-cssh/master/tmux-cssh
chmod 755 tmux-cssh
./tmux-cssh -u user host1 host2 host3 host4 host5
```

[image: tiled view of simultaneous ssh connections to 5 hosts in tmux-cssh]

Comment: It appears to have been removed from brew `Error: No available formula with the name "tmux-cssh"`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [ClusterSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/).  I have used this to great effect from an OSX 10.5 workstation, but cannot verify that it works correctly from 10.6.  I highly suspect it should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of tools for doing this.  One example is [Parallel SSH](https://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/).  It looks like you have to compile it from source for macos but it should seve as a good starting point.

This [linux.com article](http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/151340) has a good description of how pssh works.  Also, the comments on that story cover other alternatives like [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano).  I used to use Tentakel for this purpose but it looks like that project has gone dead.

Note that a lot of the tasks you might want to automate with a parallel ssh tool are really good candidates for automation with a configuration management tool like [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) or [chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home) or [cfengine](http://www.cfengine.org/).

Comment: ha I think some of us are giving the 'big answer' solutions and some the quick expedient answer solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think iTerm can do this (iterm.sf.net)

Comment: It can't send the same input to all tabs, but not establish the connections automatically, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any number of ssh multiplexers: e.g., dsh (dancer shell), pdsh. Check MacPorts.

Or, perhaps somewhat more simply: for x in $( cat hosts.txt ); do ssh $x  ; done

More complicated things, like Chef's knife, Capistrano, func, or helm, also exist.